# Check constraint exists for a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I tried following query to check whether constraint exists for a table or not.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY') IS NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE HS_HR_PEA_EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY
```

Got this error.

> Constraint 'SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY' does not belong to table
>   'HS_HR_PEA_EMPLOYEE'

Then I tried to add the constraint to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE HS_HR_PEA_EMPLOYEE
ADD CONSTRAINT SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR JS_PICKED_TIME
```

Got this one.

> There is already an object named 'SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY' in the
>   database.

What's wrong with the query. Do I have to mention table name with the schema?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
     OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName
    ,type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
    AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)='SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY'
```